# Negative Arrays and Error Messages

Tags: java, arrays

//MY TASK IS TWO MERGE TO ARRAYS INTO ASCENDING ORDER.Your program will accept each array as input from the keyboard. You do not know ahead of time how many values will be entered, but you can assume each array will have a maximum length of 10,000 elements. To stop entering values enter zero or a negative number. You should disregard any non-positive numbers input and not store these in the array.
The elements of the two input arrays should be in increasing order. In other words, each array element must have a value that is greater than or equal to the previous element value. An array may contain repeated elements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int one[]= new int[10000];  
        int two[]= new int[10000]; 

        int lengthShort=0;          

        int lengthLong=0;           



        int a =0;                   
        int b =0;                   

        System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, "
                + "up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");


        for(int i=0; i<one.length && scan.hasNext(); i++){

            one[i] = scan.nextInt();
            a++;
            if(one[i]<0){
                one[i]=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        int length1 = a-1;

        System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, "
                + "up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");

        for(int i=0; i<two.length && scan.hasNext(); i++){

            two[i] = scan.nextInt();
            b++;
            if(two[i]<0){
                two[i]=0;
                break;
            }

        }

        int lengthTwo = b-1;


        int mergeOne[] = new int[length1];  

        for (int i = 0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
            mergeOne[i]=one[i];
        }
        int mergeTwo[] = new int[lengthTwo];    

        for (int i = 0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
            mergeTwo[i]=two[i];
        }


        System.out.println("First Array:");

        for(int i=0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
        System.out.print(mergeOne[i] + " ");
        }


        System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");

        for(int i=0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
        System.out.print(mergeTwo[i] + " ");
        }


        if(mergeOne.length<=mergeTwo.length){
            lengthLong = mergeTwo.length;
            lengthShort = mergeOne.length;
        }

        else if(mergeOne.length>=mergeTwo.length){
            lengthShort = mergeTwo.length;
            lengthLong = mergeOne.length;
        }

        int merged[] = new int[length1 + lengthTwo];


        for(int i = 0; i<lengthShort; i++){
            if(i==0){
                if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                    merged[i] = mergeOne[i];
                    merged[i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
                }
                else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                    merged[i] = mergeTwo[i];
                    merged[i+1]= mergeOne[i];
                }
            }
            else if(i>0){
                if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                    merged[i+i] = mergeOne[i];
                    merged[i+i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
                }
                else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                    merged[i+i] = mergeTwo[i];
                    merged[i+i+1]= mergeOne[i];
                }
            }
        }

        if(mergeOne.length<mergeTwo.length){
            for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
                merged[k]=mergeTwo[k];
            }
        }

        if(mergeOne.length>mergeTwo.length){
                for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
                    merged[k]=mergeOne[k];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
            if((i+1)==merged.length)        
                break;
            if(merged[i]>merged[i+1]){
                int temp = merged[i+1];
                merged[i+1]=merged[i];
                merged[i]= temp;

            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nMerged array in order is: ");

        for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
        System.out.print(merged[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    }
```

//My code compiles in drjava but I have two issues:

1) It doesn't order the numbers in ascending order

2) When I run it through the site I have to submit this on it gives me the message as follows:

```
Runtime Error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at Main.main(Main.java:281)
    at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:94)
    at Ideone.test(Main.java:42)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:29)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Array.sort() method?

Comment: Please be careful not to include non-code parts in the code--it was hard to tell what question you were asking, since it didn't show up at all until I scrolled the frame with the code in it.  I've fixed it.

Comment: @barna10 I'm guessing that the point of the assignment is to write a merge algorithm.  Using `Arrays.sort()` would be cheating.

Comment: Could you let us know what line the exception is on (line 281)?  The code you've posted has only 142 lines, so I'm guessing there's some other framework code for the assignment or something.  I don't need to see the other code, but I do need to see which line is 281.

Comment: I'm trying your program out, but I can't get a `NegativeArraySizeException`.  Do you know what the input is when you get that exception, or is that hidden from you?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to rethink your merge algorithm.  Suppose you input arrays are

```
1 5 10 50 100 500
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
```

You'll need to repeatedly decide which element is smaller to put into the output.  So after selecting N elements, your output will look like

```
1 2 4 5 6 8 10 10 12 14
```

And you will need to have indexes pointing at the place in the input arrays you'll need to look at next:

```
1 5 10 50 100 500
       ^^
2 4  6  8  10  12  14  16
                       ^^
```

As you can see, the indexes could be at very different places in the input arrays.  However, your code does a lot of this:

```
if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
```

which means it's only comparing elements from the input that are in the *same* location.  This doesn't work, and trying to swap elements in the output after the fact isn't good enough to get the job done.

Basically, instead of having one index and comparing the elements of the two input arrays at the same index, you'll need two indexes.  I'll let you take it from there, but I think you can figure it out.

(And I have no idea why you're getting `NegativeArraySizeException`.)